# Aspose.Cells taking huge time to convert Excel to Tiff

Tags: c#, .net, excel, tiff, aspose

I am using Aspose Framework (Aspose.cells dll version 8.5.1).
While trying to convert large excel file(no. of sheets-11, no. of rows-23228) into tiff images of file size 20 MB. It is taking huge time to covert into tiff around 4 hours with compression "CompressionCCITT4". And without using compression it is throwing an exception. The generated Tiff file size is of 512 MB.
So I wanted to know:

1.What is the maximum size of the excel file that Aspose Cells is able to convert.

2.What is the maximum limit on number of pages or sheets.

3.What we can do to reduce the time for conversion.

Please help with issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is no restriction or limits put forth by Aspose.Cells for rendering, it works the same way as MS Excel does for creating or rendering Excel spreadsheets.

Regarding your issue “Aspose.Cells taking huge time to convert Excel to Tiff”, since you are using some older version of the product, so it might be the case. We recommend you to kindly try using latest version/fix, e.g Aspose.Cells for .NET v20.9.x or greater version. If you still find the issue, kindly post a thread in the forums (https://forum.aspose.com/c/cells/9) to provide your template Excel file and sample code, we will check it soon there.

PS. I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.